# Running MYSQL once LAMP stack has been installed

Tags: mysql

When I run mysql -u root -p, I get a message saying

```
bash: mysql: command not found
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I have talked to my system administrator and has said that the LAMP stack has been installed. Now I need to run mysql an start creating databases.

This is the email he sent:

```
Mysql 5.1.32 is already installed on the vm name@..net.
    [root@name~]# mysql -V
    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.32, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: If mysql has been installed, it is probably a path issue. Ask your sysadmin where exactly mysql was installed to.

Comment: LAMP stack is just a buzzword to say the mysql **SERVER** has been installed. It doesn't also mean the mysql client has been installed as well. OOps... and just as I post this comment, your edit comes in. So the client is installed, which means it's just not in your shell's path.

Comment: So what should I do to run the mysql server?

Comment: What output do you get when you run the command: which mysql

Comment: usr/bin/which: no mysql in (/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/name/bin)

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your mysql server is running or not.
If not then use:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Then try the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
service mysql status
```

or

```
service mysqld status
```